# Implementing a Shared Prepared SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, singleton, prepared-statement

I am writing a class that contains an array of other objects that it generates by querying a database.  Each instance of this class runs a nearly identical query so my thought was to setup a shared prepared statement handler and each class would simply bind a different variable to it.  Here is the code snippet:

```
class CQuestion
{
    // this is line 16
    static private $sthAns = SPDO::prepare(
        'SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answers.q_id = :qid'
    );

    // constructor, other functions, etc.   

    private function GetAnswers()
    {
        self::$sthAns->bindParam(':qid', $this->m_iQID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        self::$sthAns->execute();
    }

}
```

I know this doesn't work because I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mbtest\CQuestion.php on line 16

Does anyone know a way to implement this without having to reset the prepared statement for each instance of the class?

Incase there is any confusion I have wrapped PDO in my own singleton (SPDO) that sets itself through a ini file. Thats why I am accessing prepare through a static reference.

Comment: What is line 16? It looks like just a regular syntax error. Though I'm not sure if you can access a statement statically so that might be a different problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot about point that out.  I've added a note about line 16.  I am pretty sure line 16 is a syntax error, so my question is how should I do this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a method when instantiating an object/class property. You'll need to use a constructor/initializer for that. Try something like this:

```
class CQuestion
{
    private static $sthAns;

    private static function getSthAns()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$sthAns)) self::$sthAns = SPDO::prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answers.q_id = :qid'
        );
        return self::$sthAns;
    }

    private function GetAnswers()
    {
        self::getSthAns()->bindParam(':qid', $this->m_iQID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        self::getSthAns()->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, feeling a little foolish since this is, in a way, how the SPDO class is implemented.